# Developing multi threaded applications in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

This will be my first multi threaded application if it can be developed as so. So I need some help getting started.

I currently have the following JAVA program that works perfectly well

1. Get data from a source database and convert them to objects(POJOs)
2. Get data from a target database and convert them to objects(POJOs).
3. Compare both the source and target objects and if there is a difference, then update the target database with info from source database.

Now my requirement has changed and I need to use 3 different target databases(TargetDB1, TargetDB2, TargetDB3). Each one has a different connection info.

My question is , Can we make this a multi threaded application where in

Thread 1 will get source object

Thread 2 will get TargetDB1 object, compare to the source object(obtained from Thread 1) and update the TargetDB1 in case of differences with the source object

Thread 3 will get TargetDB2 object, compare to the source object(obtained from Thread 1) and update the TargetDB2 in case of differences with the source object

Thread 4 will get TargetDB2 object, compare to the sourceobject (obtained from Thread 1) and update the TargetDB2 in case of differences with the source object

If this can be developed as a multi threaded application,  then how to go about it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this through an application layer?  For large volumes, it will be faster to use database utilities.  Even simply using some SQL statements and .csv's would probably be faster.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is best way of getting the dbs in sync. If your DB1 is master DB then it is better to write an upgrade script for the other DBs in my opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't use multiple threads but I would be concerned about consistency. e.g. say DB1, 2, and 3 are different. Comparing only two at a time, you need to ensure all three databases will end up with the same values.

Comment: I am not so much conversant with the DB side scripts, but the select and update operations need multiple joins to get the data and then update. We intend to schedule this program to run every so often and update the target DBs.

Comment: @Peter, the target DBs all have the same structure, but one is in INT, one is a Dev DB and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a work queue for each of your target databases using some [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) such as a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).  The producer thread will get the object from the source database and then add it to each of the work queues.  Then each of the threads attached to a target database can dequeue from its work queue and update its database at its own speed.

Source database thread might look something like:

```
// allow only 10 outstanding objects to be in the work queue before it blocks
queue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<SourceObject>(10);
new Thread(new TargetDatabaseThread("url-to-database1", queue1)).start();
queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<SourceObject>(10);
new Thread(new TargetDatabaseThread("url-to-database2", queue2)).start();
queue3 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<SourceObject>(10);
new Thread(new TargetDatabaseThread("url-to-database3", queue3)).start();
while (true) {
    SourceObject sourceObj = getFromSourceDatabase();
    // this might block if you set a capacity on your queue and it was full
    queue1.put(sourceObj);
    queue2.put(sourceObj);
    queue3.put(sourceObj);
}
```

Each of the target database threads then might look like:

```
public class TargetDatabaseThread implements Runnable {
    private final String jdbcUrl;
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    private volatile boolean shutdown;
    public TargetDatabaseThread(String jdbcUrl, BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.jdbcUrl = jdbcUrl;
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    public void run() {
        // maybe some initialization, make database connection, etc.
        while (!shutdown) {
            // this would block if nothing is in the queue
            SourceObject sourceObj = queue.take();
            SourceObject targetObj =
                getObjectFromTargetDatabase(sourceObj.getId());
            if (updateTarget(sourceObj, targetObj)) {
               updateMyTargetObjectInDatabase(targetObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One problem with this model would be if the target database threads need to update the source object in any manner.  If this is the case then you would have to synchronize the object.

Note that blocking queues can be set with a capacity.  This would be useful in case it was easier for the producer to read from the source database than it was for the target database writers to update their databases.  You wouldn't want the queue to fill memory because the target databases are slow.

Comment: @Gary..thanks for your reply..I dont need to update the source database. Thanks for the code snippet. Since this is my first time, can you pls elaborate the code. Currently I have huge classes with a lot of methods to take care of the entire fetch, compare, ConflictCheck before update, update(both delete and insert) operations. How can I use them so that different threads will use the same program. Essentially, how do these thread classes look like and how do they get executed in the main method.

Comment: You threads would all be the same class with the same `ConflictCheck`, etc. methods.  Maybe call it `TargetDatabaseThread` or some such.  One of the arguments to their constructor would be the `BlockingQueue` they will be calling `take()` on.

Comment: @Gray..thanks..I will accept this answer and start working on this. If I get stuck ...will comeback with another question.